Density beyond Stone–Weierstrass
$\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}$I need density assertions for spaces of polynomials which are not (that I know of) algebras. One goes like this: Fix $n\in\mathbb N$ let $S$ denote the set of self-adjoint $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C$. Next fix $r\in\mathbb N$, take $S^r=S\times S\times\cdots\times S$ and let the unitary group $U(n)$ act by conjugation
$$
u.(A_1,\dots,A_r)=(uA_1u^{-1},\dots,uA_ru^{-1}).
$$
Let $X=S^r/U(n)$ denote the set of orbits. Equip it with the quotient topology.
Let $F$ denote the set of functions $f:X\to\mathbb C$ of the form
$$
f(A_1,\dots,A_r)=\tr\big(P(A_1,\dots,A_r)\big),
$$
where $\tr$ denotes the trace of a matrix and $P$ is a polynomial in $r$ non-commuting variables.
The question now is, whether $F$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ with respect to locally uniform convergence?
If not, is there a handy description of the closure $\bar F\ $?

So $S=S_1 = \cdots =S_n$? Your notation is throwing me.

Sorry, I hope it's clearer now.

I think this is hopeless. $F(A)=\|A\|$ is an invariant continuous function. We would then need a polynomial $P(x)=\sum a_jx^j$ such that $F(A)\simeq \operatorname{tr} P(A) = \sum a_j \operatorname{tr} A^j$, but things look grim as soon as we test this on a few random $A$'s: For example, taking $A=1$ and $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,\ldots , 0)$ shows that $a_0\simeq 1/n$ (and $\sum_{j\ge 1} a_j\simeq 0$), but now we're in trouble for $A=0$.

Could $r\ge 2$ change the picture?

@Nandor: No, when $A_2=\ldots = A_r=0$ we're essentially back in the $r=1$ case.

Ah yes, ok, but if we only look at those tuples $A_j$ which together generate the algebra $M_n$ of n x n matrices?
